# Views template- how can I still use "hide if empty" behavior with my custom template?

Tags: views, theming

I want to customize the output of a field on my site so I made a custom views template.  Here's the code:

```
<?php foreach ($row->field_field_location_taxonomize_terms as $data): ?>

  <?php if ($data['rendered']['#markup'] == 'Unknown'): ?>
  <?php elseif ($data['rendered']['#markup'] == 'United States of America (USA)'): ?>
    <?php print 'USA'; ?> 
  <?php elseif ($data['rendered']['#markup'] == 'United Kingdom (UK)'): ?>
    <?php print 'UK'; ?> 
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php print $data['rendered']['#markup']; ?> 
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As far as editing the output, this works fine.  However, if the field is empty, the Label (set in views) for the field will still be printed, even though I have *Hide if empty* checked under **No Results Behavior**.  If I remove my custom template, then the label is hidden when there is no value, so there must be something wrong with my template.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, how about turning the label for this field off in Views and add something like:

```
<?php if (!empty($row->field_field_location_taxonomize_terms)): ?>
  <div>Label:</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

at the top of this template?  (Changing up the HTML around Label: to match your system and t()'ing it, etc)